# Setting a HTTP Header in ProxyPass to have dynamic route

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers, environment-variables

I am setting up a request header using :

```
RequestHeader set X_FIELD "expr=%{tolower:%{req:SOME-VAL}}"
```

and want to send the value of this HTTP Header in ProxyPass.

now I want to send the same parameter we set in Request Header in ProxyPass, I have tried doing using ProxyPass balancer://someParam/%{HTTP:X_FIELD}/someUrl

Also tried it using DEFINE as well as

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-My-Header} (.+) RewriteRule ^ - [E=MY_VARIABLE:%1]
```

```
# Use the environment variable in the ProxyPass directive
ProxyPass / http://backend-server/%{ENV:MY_VARIABLE}/
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend-server/%{ENV:MY_VARIABLE}/
```

but nothing worked. Can someone help?